# Error uploading to a non-US Standard AWS S3 Bucket in Django application; US Standard bucket works perfectly

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I set up an S3 bucket in a **non-US region** (Singapore). When I try to upload images to it, I get a **301** (Permanently moved) error from S3. Researching has led me to understand that for a non-standard bucket, one must specify the particular endpoint and region.

I've tried a variety of configuration variables in my settings.py, but it never works. Note that boto and django-storages are installed, and I've gotten it to work for a US standard bucket before.

The following is how it's currently set up (plus all the different variations I've tried):

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
AWS_S3_FORCE_HTTP_URL = True
AWS_S3_SECURE_URLS = False
AWS_S3_URL_PROTOCOL = 'http'
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('awssecretkey')
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('awsaccesskeyid')
AWS_S3_CALLING_FORMAT='boto.s3.connection.OrdinaryCallingFormat'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'bucket.my'
#HOST ='s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com'
#AWS_ENDPOINT = 's3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com'
#AWS_S3_REGION = 's3-ap-southeast-1'
#REGION = 's3-ap-southeast-1'
#AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
#BOTO_S3_HOST = 'bucket.my.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com'
#S3_HOST = 'http://bucket.my.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com'
#'bucket.my.s3-website-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com'
#'s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com'
#BOTO_BUCKET_LOCATION = 'Singapore'

#S3Connection.DefaultHost = 's3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com'
#HOST = 'http://bucket.my.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com'
```

Can anyone help me with the correct configuration? I'll provide more details in case you need them.

Comment: please edit your question and include the errors you receive.

Comment: @tedder42: it's **always** the 301 permanently removed error. I.e., it assumes the default; that the bucket is US-Standard. None of the variations above ever produced anything other than the 301 error. But feel free to tell me how you'd have done it, I'm going to try it even if I've tried it before (sometimes one can miss a small-yet-important distinction).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using the current version of django-storages-redux and had to use the following in settings.py in order to use the Sydney S3 region.

```
import boto
from boto.s3.connection import OrdinaryCallingFormat, Location

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'XXX'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'XXX'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'my.bucket.name'
AWS_AUTO_CREATE_BUCKET = False
AWS_S3_HOST = 's3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com'
AWS_S3_CALLING_FORMAT = 'boto.s3.connection.OrdinaryCallingFormat'
```

Note the AWS_S3_HOST value; that is the parameter that I needed to solve the "301 (Permanently moved)" error.

Answer (score 2):

"Singapore" is not a valid "region" in the sense that you need, here:

```
AWS_S3_REGION = 'ap-southeast-1'
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region

This may not be the only issue, but it should be one of the issues, at least.

Comment: Sadly both didn't work. Note that if I change AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME to a US Standard bucket, my code works correctly (meaning all dependencies are correctly set up?)

Comment: Ugh.  Yes, if it works in US-Standard that suggests that the dependencies are in order.  The region should be "ap-southeast-1" ... note that VHostCallingFormat should be fine if you are *not* using SSL.

Comment: Noted the Calling Format Michael (thanks). Vis-a-vis how to point to the correct endpoint/region, any other leads you could provide me? I'm experimenting quite a bit here now.

Comment: I write all my own code for interaction with AWS, speaking the raw native formats the APIs expect, instead of using any libraries or SDKs, exactly for this reason -- I don't like the hidden functionality and the guesswork.  I should probably remove this answer, since it does not fully solve the problem of "convincing" the underlying code do do the right thing.  I don't have any further suggestions.

Comment: Keep it, might help someone else because there's not much regarding this particular approach (for Django) on SO. I'll also edit my ques to include all the config I've tried since yesterday. Maybe someone else has a light bulb moment. I might ultimately just take your approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
AWS_AUTO_CREATE_BUCKET = True
AWS_S3_HOST = 's3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com'
```

This works also for django-storages. Thanks @gmcc051