# S3ResponseError: 301 Moved Permanently - Django

Tags: django, amazon-s3

I have a very big issue with Amazon S3. I am working on a Django app and I want to store file on S3:
My settings are:

```
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'tfjm2-inscriptions'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'id'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'key'
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
```

And I get this error: S3ResponseError: 301 Moved Permanently

Some same issues on the Internet say that it is because it is a non-US bucket and I did tried with a US-standard bucket but it get a 401 Forbidden error.....

I do not know what to do.

Please help me.

Thank you

Comment: Do you know what did you do before having this error? Did you check on AWS webconsole if your resources are still there?

Comment: I did check, all my static files are still there: I have this error where "media" is a folder in my S3 <Error><Code>PermanentRedirect</Code><Message>The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.</Message><Bucket>media</Bucket><Endpoint>s3.amazonaws.com</Endpoint>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error uploading to a non-US Standard AWS S3 Bucket in Django application; US Standard bucket works perfectly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32699287/error-uploading-to-a-non-us-standard-aws-s3-bucket-in-django-application-us-sta)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

`AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME`

Answer (score 1):

Solve by changing your code to:

```
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'tfjm2-inscriptions'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'id'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'key'
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = 'us-east-2' ##### Use the region name where your bucket is created
```

AWS allow you to create and access buckets in the same region as an optimization measure and as such if you create a bucket in say 'us-west-2' you'll get a 301 if you try accessing it from a different region (Africa, Europe and even East US).

You should specify the region if requesting the bucket from outside its region.

Answer (score 0):

in terminal run 'nano ~/.boto'
if there is some configs try to comment or rename file and connect again. (it helps me)
http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/boto_config_tut.html
there is boto config file directories. take a look one by one and clean them all, it will work by default configs. also configs may be in .bash_profile, .bash_source... 
I guess you must allow only KEY-SECRET